# Converting Date String to different Format

Tags: swift

I have myString "28-OCT-22"
I need to convert it to different format "dd.MM.yyyy"
What I've tried:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d-MMM-yy"
                    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: myString)! //error, I think because OCT is uppercase, NSDateFormatter doesn't have this format?
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
                    let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

and is there more clean way to do this?

Comment: What is the source of this `28-OCT-22` string? Did you capture in the UI, or is it something you received from a web service and/or extracted from a database. And what is the purpose of the `28.10.2022` string. Again, for UI or for internal purposes within the app. Below, vadian assumed that none of these date strings would ever be shown in the UI, in which case using `en_US_POSIX` is fine. But if one or more of these date strings would appear in the UI, then using `en_US_POSIX` would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Month abbreviations are localized.

Set the locale to the fixed generic value `en_US_POSIX` which supports `OCT`

```
let myString = "28-OCT-22"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d-MMM-yy"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: myString)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Although the format is correct force unwrapping converted dates is not recommended